# Testing Android activity

Tags: android, testing

This is my method

```
@MediumTest
public void testLoginSenzaCredenziali() {

    Button btn_login = (Button) mActiviy.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    EditText txt_username = (EditText) mActiviy.findViewById(R.id.txt_login_username);
    EditText txt_password = (EditText) mActiviy.findViewById(R.id.txt_login_password);

    assertNotNull("Button btn_login non può essere nullo", btn_login);
    assertNotNull("EditText txt_username non può essere nullo", txt_username);
    assertNotNull("EditText txt_password non può essere nullo", txt_password);
    assertEquals("EditText txt_username deve essere vuota", "", txt_username.getText());
    assertEquals("EditText txt_password deve essere vuota", "", txt_password.getText());


}
```

The class header is

```
public class LoginTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<LoginActivity>
```

but when in Android Studio I run it, it doesn't recognize my test method, it says "Empty test suite".

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You also need the to override the setUp() method in your ActivityUnitTestCase:

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}
```

Did you install the application under test on the device or emulator?  Check that the instrumentation app is also installed by running this command:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

Look for your test package - the same one you defined in your **AndroidManifest.xml** under the test project.